# How to execute a function on woocommerce_order_status_completed hook for specific product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to run a specific function on woocommerce_order_status_completed, if the order contains a specific product. Can someone help it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
function woo_update_status($order_id)
{
  $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
  foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values) :
    $item_data = $item_values->get_data();
    $item_id = $item_values->get_id(); //Product id
    $product_name = $item_data['name']; //Product name
  endforeach;
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','woo_update_status');
```